# How to pass value from html input tag to php code?

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

My patient_display.php code calls patient_history.php file passing the P_ID. Below is my code.

```
patient_display.php:
echo '<form name="Patient" action="patient_history_display.php" method="get">';
$pid=$_GET["patient_id"];
echo '<input type="text" name="p_id" value= '.$pid.' >';
</form>

patient_history.php:
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT P.P_F_NAME, P.P_L_NAME,P.P_ADDR,     round(datediff(now(),P.P_DOB)/365) AS P_AGE, D.D_DESC, A.A_DESC 
FROM P_HAS_A  PA, patient P, P_HAS_D PD, n_provide_m NM, disease D, allergy A 
WHERE P.P_ID = PD.P_ID AND PD.D_ID = D.D_ID AND P.P_ID = PA.P_ID AND PA.A_ID = A.A_ID AND P.P_ID='{$_GET["p_id"]}';");
$pid=$_GET["p_id"];
```

However, it is throwing the below error
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
Notice: Undefined index: p_id in

Comment: Remove $pid=$_GET["patient_id"]; from patient_display.php:

Comment: do u mean to change code as below?                                    echo '<input type="text" name="p_id" value= '$_GET["patient_id"]'>';

Comment: did you get value for p_id in that line ??

Comment: oh sorry I havent seen the below line. Like @Jenz said are you getting the value for pid ?

Comment: in which line you are getting the error. Share the complete error message.

Comment: SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: p_id in C:\wamp\www\Project\db2\db2\patient_history_display.php on line 124
Call Stack # Time Memory Function Location 1 0.0008 696312 {main}( ) ..\patient_history_display.php:0. The line 124 is $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT P.P_F_NAME, P.P_L_NAME,P.P_ADDR, round(datediff(now(),P.P_DOB)/365) AS P_AGE, D.D_DESC, A.A_DESC FROM P_HAS_A  PA, patient P, P_HAS_D PD, n_provide_m NM, disease D, allergy A WHERE P.P_ID = PD.P_ID AND PD.D_ID = D.D_ID AND P.P_ID = PA.P_ID AND PA.A_ID = A.A_ID AND P.P_ID='{$_GET["p_id"]}';");

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Answer (score 0):

Just check before using $_GET and $_POST whether its value set(exists) or not.
You can use '@','isset','strlen' and '!empty'.
so your condition would be

```
 if(isset($_GET['patient_id'])) { 
   $id = $_GET['patient_id'];
   echo '<input type="text" name="p_id" value= '.$pid.' >';
 }
```

and same for `$_GET['p_id']`

Comment: can you paste your url params here?

Comment: URL params?? ...i am sorry i did not get you.

Comment: Your URL from which you are using $_GET['patient_id'] and $_GET['p_id']

Comment: i have used in SQL query to compare the data with the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have error in the sql. Try with this:

```
$pid=$_GET["p_id"];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT P.P_F_NAME, P.P_L_NAME,P.P_ADDR,     round(datediff(now(),P.P_DOB)/365) AS P_AGE, D.D_DESC, A.A_DESC 
FROM P_HAS_A  PA, patient P, P_HAS_D PD, n_provide_m NM, disease D, allergy A 
WHERE P.P_ID = PD.P_ID AND PD.D_ID = D.D_ID AND P.P_ID = PA.P_ID AND PA.A_ID = A.A_ID AND P.P_ID='$pid'");
```

Comment: Yes. In where clause. Can i use post form rather than get form?

Comment: If you are getting the value of $pid then the query should work. Try with the query in my updated answer.

Comment: why not use joins instead of that long where clause?

Comment: I don't whether you are getting the value of $pid in that page or not..If not, then try with post..

Comment: I tried with post. The value which is passed is "View Patient History" . i think from this code echo '<input type="submit"  name="p_id" value="View Patient History">';
echo '</form>';   rather the actual p_id value.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo '<form name="Patient" action="patient_history.php" method="get">';
$pid=$_GET["p_id"];
echo '<input type="text" name="p_id" value= '.@$pid.' >';
</form>
```

And patient_history.php:

```
$pid = $_GET['p_id'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT P.P_F_NAME, P.P_L_NAME,P.P_ADDR,
round(datediff(now(),P.P_DOB)/365) AS P_AGE, D.D_DESC, A.A_DESC 
FROM P_HAS_A  PA, patient P, P_HAS_D PD, n_provide_m NM, disease D, allergy A 
WHERE P.P_ID = PD.P_ID AND PD.D_ID = D.D_ID AND P.P_ID = PA.P_ID AND PA.A_ID = A.A_ID AND
P.P_ID='{$pid';");
```